# SSRS - Exporting grouped report to Excel shows top row twice when expanding the group

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

It seems whenever I export an expandable report to Excel, it reads the first line as a header or footer or something and duplicates that line so it shows up at the top and bottom of the group.

Example of one grouped item in Excel

[image]

As you can see the first and last lines are identical, but only that top line should be there. Is these any way to avoid this when exporting collapsible groups to Excel? The issue doesn't seem to occur when exporting to other formats and the lines are not duplicated in the report itself.

Comment: What does it look like in report server? Does it show any data when the row is collapsed? A pic of your design view might help, too. I think this may be a quirk in the excel rendering.

Comment: It shows that first row of data when collapsed. When expanded in the report, it only has the line once and not again at the bottom of the grouping. But I suspected this was probably more on Excel's side.

Comment: I was thinking that you may have data when it's not expanded which is causing the issue in the Excel rendering since Excel needs something in that row.  I usually have totals and averages in top lines like this. If you really wanted to keep this format, you could use an expression to not show data in Excel - `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML", NOTHING, Fields!Data.Value)`

Comment: I don't want to have any headers with totals or anything like that. When there are headers, then I don't see this issue as that first line will be the header. Where would that expression go?